# CreateFile() return an invalid pointer with the address FFFFFF

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, createfile

I just want to read a file using the function CreateFile such as following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pImageDosHeader;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    HANDLE hMapObject;
    PUCHAR uFileMap;
    if (argc < 2)
        return (-1);
    std::cout << "hFile=" << hFile << std::endl;
    if (!(hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)argv[1], GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)))
    {
        return (-1);
    } else {
        std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "hFile=" << hFile << std::endl;
        getchar();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The problem is that the output is like below :

> hFile=000000 (the pointer is initialized to NULL -> OK)
>
> hFile=FFFFFF (invalid pointer)

Does anyone can help me, please ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you'll find that it's actually 8 F's. That's the value for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. A `hFile=0` is a valid result, `-1` is invalid. You should call `GetLastError()` to give an answer as to "why is it invalid" - it could be many things, the most likely that you are trying to open an existing file that doesn't exist (e.g. you are in the wrong directory, perhaps?)

Comment: MSDN is your friend. Read the documentation.

Comment: I'd recommend you run it through a debugger and put a breakpoint before CreateFile and take a look to see if argv[1] is the value you expect it to be and also check the file exists. As mentioned above "msdn is your friend" so look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Others have pointed out the problem with 0 being a valid handle (where you expect it not to be). I believe the cause of getting the invalid handle is casting `argv[1]` to `(LPCWSTR)`. This tells the program "take this array of ASCII characters and iterpret the bytes therein as wide characters." Not what you want, I believe. Either use `wmain()`, or call `CreateFileA()`.

Comment: Hello, yes the getLastError() return the value 2. My file is in my VS project. So I just added the name of my file (test1.txt containing the string "Hello world") . To be sure I added in my code a std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]) + just below a loop with a getline. After execution I print the buffer which contains the string "Hello world". So it's not a file path problem.

Comment: tip: when you debug add this to your watch window `@err,hr` it will automatically show error message after every API call, so you won't need to decrypt the error code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
if (!(hFile = CreateFile(...)))
```

is not how you check for errors.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the function fails, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is `-1`, or `0xFFFFFFFFF` in hex. You need to call `GetLastError()` to find out what happened.

Comment: Hello, yes the getLastError() return the value 2. My file is in my VS project. So I just added the name of my file (test1.txt containing the string "Hello world") . To be sure I added in my code a std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]) + just below a loop with a getline. After execution I print the buffer which contains the string "Hello world". So it's not a file path problem. What does the error 2 mean ?

Comment: @user1364743: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error from most Win32 APIs, you can call `GetLastError()` to find out what went wrong.  Take it from there.

This type of defensive programming is essential for productive Win32 programming.  The actual conditions for a failure vary by API, so use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check what you should be looking for in your failure codepaths.